# Wait for Mail to send then delete it from sent-folder in PowerShell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook-2010, outlook-redemption

I'm currently writing a script to automatically send some mails.
I want to send an automated mail, and for purpose of a clean mailbox I want these automated mails to be deleted from the sent-folder straight away.

I have got the script so far as to send the mail, and I also have written a perfectly functioning function that clears the sent-folder.

The problem is that the mail will remain in the outbox while it is being sent and only enters the sent-folder when it is in fact sent, but by then my script will have ended and the Clear-function will have passed without having cleared the mail.

I will need some sort of timer or if possible some triggered event for when the mail is in fact sent and stored in the sent-folder.

### Code:

```
function Send
{
    $mItem = $ol.CreateItem(0)
    $mail = $routlook.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject($mItem)

    $mail.To = "users@mail.com"
    $mail.Subject = "some subject"
    $mail.Body = "some body stuff"
    $mail.Attachments.Add("<path to attachment>")

    $mail.Send()
    Clear


}

function Clear
{
    $SItems = $sent.Items
    foreach($s in $SItems)
    {
        if( $s.To -eq "'user@mail.com'")
        {
            $s.Delete()
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit` property to true - the message will never be moved to the Sent Items folder after it is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Don't send mail through Outlook in the first place, unless you absolutely must for some odd reason. Use [`Send-Mailmessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) instead.

```bsh
Send-MailMessage -to users@mail.com -subject "Some Subject" -body "some body stuff" -attachments <Collection of file paths> -SmtpServer Your_SMTP_HOST -from fromuser@mail.com
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It's a script for a work-related e-mail so our exchange server will reject `Send-MailMessage`due to policy-reason. This was the only way I could think of and that works to be able to send mails.

Comment: It should still be possible to send via `Send-Mailmessage` - you just have to know what "policy" is causing the rejection and use the appropriate parameters to satisfy it.

Comment: Any idea how I can find out without talking to the server admin? some sort of reverse engineering method perhaps? or how detailed must a mail be ?

Comment: Start by using the cmdlet and research the errors that you receive. If you get stuck on one which you can't fix yourself, ask your admin.